# Is there any difference between being a Zionist and being a Jew?

Tags: zionism

apparently Zionist means someone believing in returning to somewhere called the promised land, and I don't know much about being a jew but I guess believing in promised land is an important principle as well, so is there a difference? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a dictionary?

Comment: There are many different flavors of Zionism and different subtleties to each. Some refining would be necessary before anyone could truly answer this.

Comment: You're basically asking, "Is there a difference between being a redhead and wearing green?"  Sure, lots of redheads wear green since it goes nicely with traditional redhead hair and complexion, but plenty of redheads do not wear green, and plenty of non-redheads wear green.  There is a significant difference between the two.  Judaism is a religion, Zionism is a political philosophy (a specific form of nationalism), and Jews are a people.  You can be a Jew without caring a lick about Judaism, you can care about Judaism and reject Zionism, or you can be a Zionist and neither of the other two.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Zionism) is an article about Christian Zionism.  With Zionism as you defined it in your question, there is a big difference to being a Zionist and being a Jew.

With Wikipedia's [definition of Zionism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zionism), this is a "movement of Jews and Jewish culture" by definition.  Someone could ostensibly be a member of Jewish culture and not a Jew (many children of intermarriages may fit this category) and would therefore seemingly fit this definition of Zionism.

In any case, your question assumes that all people who agree to a certain fact are the same.  You cannot distill almost any belief system in to one belief.  Zionism *may* be a subset of Judaism, but they are by far not the same.  Much similar to the famous analogy of a square being a rectangle.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I'm not sure what that is more illustrative of.  A square can be red just as much as a rectangle could be a square.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Right - a non-square can also be a rectangle.  That is the point of the mashal.